# ${GIT_URL} parameter in Jenkins not being detected

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins jobs set up which track master and feature branches of my development. Both have same structure of sub-jobs. Both have Repository URL set to the same repository. And in the configuration of sub-jobs, I write ${GIT_URL} as the repository URL. The set-up works for Master job but the feature job fails with the following error.

stderr: fatal: '${GIT_URL}' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Everything is same. I don't know why only this job chain gives the error. Also, note that if i replace the ${GIT_URL} with the repository name, then Jenkins does not throw the above error. Its frustrating. Is there anybody out there who can help? Thanks a lot in advance.

[Feature branch SCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxOpX.png)

[Develop branch SCM config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnRnI.png)

Comment: Can you add some screen shots for your two jobs? (I would like to see the SCM config)

Comment: I was unable to add an image to the comment. I am sort of new here and going through meta stack questions, there are workarounds and stuff. I have added them to the question. Sorry if its not a good practice. And coming to the point, the feature branch fails with the error. The develop branch runs fine. To my naked eyes i do not see any differences in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the images. It's really an odd problem :( In your two jobs, you create a GIT_URL parameter? I don't understand why it's not working...

Comment: Yes its sort of really irritating and annoying. Just to give an additional piece of information, I used Jenkins CLI scripts to put these job xml's on the server. The feature branch xml's were just a copy of the develop branch and I just renamed them. But I think its not an issue because both these branches use the same repo URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined the problem. Since I have a set up where there is a main job followed by sub-jobs, the GIT_URL parameter has to be passed from the main job. I was under the impression that the GIT_URL was an internal Jenkins variable and did not have to be passed because Jenkins would automatically resolve it as the Repository URL. But that's not the case. In the main job at the place where I define the sub-jobs it is necessary to pass Add the Predefined Parameters section and set it as GIT_URL=${GIT_URL}. Also enable the option pass Current Build Parameters to make it work.

Comment: Can you show how it should look like in the Jenkinsfile, please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, more precisely I had this in my build logs:

`No such property: GIT_URL for class: WorkflowScript`

In my case, the problem was due to Jenkins trying to access some cache directories it couldn't, because didn't have the proper file permissions. The cache directories were like `/var/jenkins_home/caches/git-e4b7ba431ad7acf1076303d1d152fdf0`. You can see exactly which cache directory by doing a "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" and looking at "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log", in case you are working with a multibranch pipeline.

Delete the cache directories, or changing their permissions, solved the problem.